# Oracle database authentication using kerberos and AD

Tags: oracle, kerberos

We are in the planning phase of configuring our soon-to-be-upgraded databases (19c) to authenticate directly against AD (no oracle proxy). I have read a handful of documents from Oracle on how to do this. Most of the documentation focuses around using passwords (password filter/verifier). The only problem is that our AD administrators are dead-set against implementing Oracle's password filter into our existing AD infrastructure. That being said, one of the security guys said we could implement the oracle authentication using Kerberos instead. From what I have read, and the documents are scattered all over the place, and nothing that detailed, to use Kerberos:
1) The client no longer uses a username/password - they connect using a wallet-style connection (e.g. /@dbname)
2) Not only does the Oracle DB need some configuration changes, but so does every client that plans on using Kerberos

I don't know anything about Kerberos, how it works, and what goes on when you implement this, but I was hoping for, at the end of this is:
1) No client changes/installs (only the oracle DB would have config changes)
  The user will continue to provide credentials as before - completely transparent
2) No need for the password filter as our admins have a "beef" against it

So my question is:
If using Kerberos directly against AD on >=18c:

1) Does the client user still provide a username and password to authenticate against AD, or does the client simply get "accepted" due to the tickets/tokens/configuration that occurs on the client (i.e. the client is simply trusted)?

2) Is there client config changes that need to occur, or does the client reach out to the DB and the DB, with its config changes, does all the legwork to authenticate against AD based off of client info being passed

3) Does any additional manual component need to occur on occasion (periodically retrieving a ticket/token/something) (because, say, it expires)

So in the end, we want to have complete transparency with every client and using something other than the password verifier with AD.

Thanks in advance.

-Jim

Comment: FYI, For all of those that are trying to enable Oracle Centrally Managed Users with Active Directory and Kerberos, I have finally completed the task (only took me about 6 months). I have detailed instructions on how to achieve this. If you have a similar task and would like some help, let me know and I can provide you with my documentation.

Comment: Jim - I'm interested in what you learned - what's the best way to get in touch?

Comment: Hi there. I have learned a ton about this entire process. I have an extensive document that I have built that explains (hopefully) everything - how it works, how to install/configure/implement, gotchas, etc. If you'd like a copy, let me know your e-mail address and I'll send it to you. I'll have to redact certain components. If you're interested in setting this up in your environment, this will save you weeks of headaches. Let me know.

Comment: Jim - I am at martin.herbener@education.ky.gov - thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to authenticate Windows clients against an Oracle database over a network using Active Directory without making any client changes.

This is pretty open-ended and complex StackOverflow question.

Probably you've been reading the docs about [Third Party Network Authentication using Oracle Advanced Security](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/network.102/b14266/authmeth.htm#i1009853). You can use Kerberos, SSL, RADIUS, PKI, etc. For most of these options, you need to do some setup on the client, because both the Oracle client and server need to authenticate or verify with the third-party system.

I think you need [Enterprise User Security](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/dbimi/introducing-enterprise-user-security.html) (using Oracle Internet Directory). Assuming you go with password-based authentication, you don't need client changes. In this scenario, Oracle Internet Directory can synchronize its user directory with AD, so your users can use their same username/password. However, when they change their AD password, they'll need to change their Oracle password separately.

On a different note, you may be able to alleviate your AD admins' fears about Oracle password complexity requirements, since [you can change or remove those](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/authentication.htm#DBSEG342) to fit your AD requirements.